# String Substring is not working - Error starting index can not be larger than the length

Tags: c#

[image]

[image]

The error keeps saying "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"

```
IntializedPorts[i] = int.Parse(ports[i].ToString().Substring(105, 106));
//I tried this too
IntializedPorts[i] = int.Parse(ports[i].ToString().Substring(105, 1));
//this works, this gets the first number in the string that would be five
IntializedPorts[i] = int.Parse(ports[i].ToString().Substring(0, 1));
```

//The string I'm trying to substring, Im trying to get the number 7 at the end of the ipaddress in the string

```
5b5bfdfe-6eb1-4b10-80af-cf4d9f1010fe3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277FastTrackVirusSoftware192.168.6.17TCP/IPYESReady8/4/2013 1:07:43 PM9/1/2013 1:07:43 PM
```

Comment: It means that the size of the string that you have is less than 105

Comment: Try simply `IntializedPorts[i] = int.Parse(ports[i].ToString().Substring(105, 1));`

Comment: I would use Regex to extract the IP and then get the last number from the value returned from the regex

Comment: Are you assuming that that is your string or did you actually print out `ports[i].toString()`?

Comment: I tried that is keeps saying the same thing

Comment: Clearly the string you *think* it's using isn't the one it's actually using.  Try tracing `ports[i].ToString()` e.g. `Trace.WriteLine(ports[i].ToString())`  It's _extremely_ unlikely that Substring doesn't know the correct length of the string.

Comment: im converting it into a number im trying to get the number from the string

Comment: [The First Rule of Programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html).

Comment: I don't think `ports[i]` is actually the string you posted.  Did you look at the value under the debugger?

Comment: how would I use regex

Comment: yes I posted the value

Comment: You need to run the code @PeterRitchie commented and put that output in your question.

Comment: @Dan Hunex: I would not. There are better ways to solve the problem *here*, and parsing IP addresses with regular expressions is prone to error (*every* mortal human's first attempt with a regular expression will parse `999.999.999.999` as a valid IP address; oops!)

Comment: `"5b5bfdfe-6eb1-4b10-80af-cf4d9f1010fe3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277FastTrackVirusSoftware192.168.6.17TCP/IPYESReady8/4/2013 1:07:43 PM9/1/2013 1:07:43 PM".Substring(105, 1)` works fine, so the value is *clearly not* what you think it is.

Comment: @shawn: Granting that you are correct that *that* line of code is throwing an exception with the message that you report, I do *not* believe that `ports[i]` is equal to "`5b5bfdfe-6eb1-4b10-80af-cf4d9f1010fe3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277FastTrackVirusSoftware192.168.6.17TCP/IPYESReady8/4/2013 1:07:43 PM9/1/2013 1:07:43 PM`".

Comment: @Jason Look if use a regex that says 999.999.999.999 as an ip, it is retard but regex such as this "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";) would the job. But using a hardcoded index is more error prone , what is the position of the ip changes in that string, :(

Comment: @Dan Hunex: That's complexity that bought you absolutely nothing. And asking "what if the position of the IP address changes" is a red herring because we don't know what the actual specification for this string is.

Comment: @shawn: I want you to post a screenshot showing the exception being thrown, and type the following expression into the watch list in the debugger: "`ports[i].ToString()`" and I want to see a screenshot of the result of that expression.

Comment: im not getting the ip address, Im getting a port number that is wrapped in a xml document

Comment: where do i send the screen shot

Comment: @shawn the error is explanatory. your string length is <105

Comment: i want the starting index of the substring to start at the 105 position and stop one length over, the idea is to omit all the stuff before the value 7 at the end of the ipaddress

Comment: I added an image of the working code

Comment: `ports` contains the string you want, `ports[i]` gives you **one character**--which explains your error.

Comment: ok, it gave me the first characters in the zero starting index with a length of one which worked, so why can I not get the 105 starting index and get the length of one. that's what im trying to figure they are both one character

Comment: the only difference is one is a 5 and the other is a 7

Comment: ok i understand what you mean, how do i break it so i can change the starting index and treat it a like multi index string value, isn't there a break command not a for loop break, but a break string

Comment: cause this means the only starting index that is allowed is zero to what ever length which renders me unable to omit value prior to the value I'm trying to get unless I can break it some how

Comment: The problem is *now* screaming clear. You shouldn't be indexing into `ports` because `ports` is a `string` and `ports[i]` is merely the `ith` character of that string; of course *that* (when converted to a string) does not have an index 105. As Peter Ritchie and I both said, there is *no* way in hell that `ports[i]` was actually equal to the string that you claimed it was. Your solution is simple: you want `ports.Substring(105, 1)` as a *start* (it can be *argued* that you should compute the index as a function of some known specification of the input string, but we don't have that spec).

Comment: You guys are right, the methodology was incorrect so I have taken a different approach to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the character before *"TCP/IP"*

```
string line = "5b5bfdfe-6eb1-4b10-80af-cf4d9f1010fe3fc8ffa1-c16b-4d7b-9e55-1e88dfe15277FastTrackVirusSoftware192.168.6.17TCP/IPYESReady8/4/2013 1:07:43 PM9/1/2013 1:07:43 PM";
var num = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("TCP/IP") - 1, 1);
```

Comment: but my string is a collection

Comment: I don't see anything about it anywhere in your question, but think of this `line = ports[i].ToString()`

Comment: @shawn: A `string` can not be a collection. It is a `string`.

Comment: is there a way that I can just look up a particular value in the string since the substring is not working

Comment: @shawn: `String.Substring` is working, you're just using it wrong. There is *something* you are not telling us.

Comment: My array ports loops through a collection if you notice the i incriminator its looping and parsing a specified location that's what the substring is for

Comment: //this works, this gets the first number in the string that would be five
IntializedPorts[i] = int.Parse(ports[i].ToString().Substring(0, 1));

Comment: @shawn: No, we aren't seeing what *you* mean. Are you seeing what *we* meant? We told you *you're doing it wrong*. We asked you, are you sure that `ports[i]` is equal to the string that you claim it's equal to? Because we told you that it couldn't possibly be. We told you to check it with a `Console.WriteLine` or in the debugger. You kept insisting that `ports[i]` was equal to the claimed string but that was clearly impossible. That's why I asked for the screenshot.

Comment: Your right, this string can only have a starting index of zero, so anything above zero in the starting index will be incorrect so I am agreeing with you, I have not noticed that, until it was mentioned. I figured that each document has to be grouped according to it service type in order to get the right ports. I have taken a different approach thanks for you help though guys

Answer (score 1):

According to your screen shot, `ports` is a string.  Thus, your reference to `ports[i]` is grabbing a single character from that string and calling `.ToString()` on that.  This would be a string of length 1, which would cause the exception you posted.

Change your code to:

```
IntializedPorts[i] = int.Parse(ports.Substring(105, 1));
```

And it should work.